# Websphere Commerce Custom REST service for Login using social sign in not generating valid WC Tokens and CTXMGMT table not getting updated

Tags: rest, websphere-commerce, wcs, wcsession

In the current website, social login is implemented using the mapping in struts and it will call the custom controller command "XYZThirdPartyLoginCmdImpl" which will authenticate the details passed and it will call the out of the box "LogonCmd" for login.

For creating a REST service for the above functinality, created a custom REST handler " XYZThirdPartyLoginHandler" and from there called the existing command "XYZThirdPartyLoginCmdImpl" using the method executeControllerCommandWithContext. Once the response is generated, WCToken and WCTrustedToken is generated by the below code.

```
ActivityToken token = getActivityToken();
String identitySignature = token.getSignature();
String identityId = token.getActivityGUID().getGUID().toString();


Map<String, Object> identityTokenInfo = new HashMap();
identityTokenInfo.put(MemberFacadeConstants.EC_USERID, new String[] { userId.toString() } );
identityTokenInfo.put(MemberFacadeConstants.ACTIVITY_TOKEN_ID, new String[] { identityId } );
identityTokenInfo.put(MemberFacadeConstants.ACTIVITY_TOKEN_SIGNATURE, new String[] { identitySignature } );
Map<String, String> commerceTokens = CommerceTokenHelper.generateCommerceTokens(identityTokenInfo);

String wcToken = commerceTokens.get(CommerceTokenHelper.WC_TOKEN);
String wcTrustedToken = commerceTokens.get(CommerceTokenHelper.WC_TRUSTED_TOKEN);
```

The tokens generated using this is not valid. If we try to invoke any other rest service using this token it shows invalid user session error. "XYZThirdPartyLoginCmdImpl" authentication is success as the userId returned is correct. After executing this the user context is not getting created in CTXMGMT table.
Please guide on how to generate the valid tokens in REST flow in this use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on v9, you might want to investigate the oauth_validate REST call (/wcs/resources/store//loginidentity/oauth_validate). See the KC article for more information: [https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_9.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.integration.doc/tasks/tcv_sociallogin.htm][1]. This calls some different commands (OAuthTokenValidationCmdImpl and OpenUserRegisterCmd) than what you might be using, but it allows you to pass in a 3rd party token, and it generates the right tokens.